# How to transform a JSON String into a new table in Bigquery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a lot of raw data into one of my tables in `Bigquery` and from this raw data I need to create a new table.

Raw data table have a column named `raw_output` this column contains a `JSON` object that was stringify. It looks like that:

```
| raw_output                                                            |
| ----------------------------------------------------------------------|
| {"client":"A9310","c_integration":"889625","idntf":false,"nf_p":8.32} |
| {"client":"VB050","c_integration":"236590","idntf":true,"nf_p":4.36}  |
| {"client":"XT5543","c_integration":"326957","idntf":true,"nf_p":2.33} |
```

From this table I would like to get something like:

| client | c_integration | idntf | nf_p |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A9310 | 889625 | false | 8.32 |
| VB050 | 236590 | true | 4.36 |
| XT5543 | 326957 | true | 2.33 |

So I can perform `JOINS` and do other operations with the data, I have looked into google's BQ docs (JSON functions) but I was not able to get the expected output. Any idea/solution is much appreciated.

Thank you all in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should help

```
with raw_data as (
  select '{"client":"A9310","c_integration":"889625","idntf":false,"nf_p":8.32}' as raw_input union all
  select '{"client":"VB050","c_integration":"236590","idntf":true,"nf_p":4.36}'  as raw_input union all
  select '{"client":"XT5543","c_integration":"326957","idntf":true,"nf_p":2.33}' as raw_input
)
select 
  json_extract_scalar(raw_input, '$.client' ) as client,
  json_extract_scalar(raw_input, '$.c_integration' ) as c_integration,
  json_extract_scalar(raw_input, '$.idntf' ) as idntf,
  json_extract_scalar(raw_input, '$.nf_p' ) as nf_p 
from raw_data
```